# How do we upload a file to digitial ocean spaces using PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, digital-ocean

I need to upload a file to digital ocean spaces server using a PHP codeigniter project. If anyone have a working sample please share.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know DigitalOcean's Spaces provide cloud storage for static content for your sites and it provides a CDN service too. I know that you can use their API to manipulate the buckets, may be they have API to upload files too. A simple Googling got me this link https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/
You can use php cURL to upload files using their API.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post link-only answer. If the link contains the information needed to solve the issue, please include the actual solution in the answer and post the link as reference. If it's just a suggestion that _might_ help the OP, then it should rather be a comment. If you don't have enough rep to comment, then work on that first.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the spacesAPI, it's not complete.

Use the AWS SDK

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

        $this->client  = new S3Client([
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region'  => 'region',
                'endpoint' => 'https://region.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                'credentials' => [
                        'key'    => $mod->key,
                        'secret' => $mod->secret,
                 ]
       ])
```

Region is where you space is. For DO it apparently doesn't matter or increase speed anyway. Then you can upload the file directly with

```
$result = $this->client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => 'data_from_file.txt',
    'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,
    'Metadata'   => array(
        'Foo' => 'abc',
        'Baz' => '123'
    )
));
```

Comment: You should provide links or snippets to get the SDK. Not everyone is competent. ;) 
To install AWS SDK use the following command.  
`php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php`